# MySQL Order by before group by in view (No Sub-Querys)

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, view

I realize this question has been asked quite a few times, however i haven't managed to find a working solution for my case.

Essentially my problem arises because MySQL Doesn't allow sub-querys in views.
I found a few workarounds but they don't seem to work.

In more detail...

My first table (competitions) stores a users competitions:

```
id_tournament | id_competition | id_user | result
-------------------------------------------------
       1      |        1       |     1   |   10
       1      |        1       |     2   |   30
       1      |        2       |     1   |   20
       1      |        2       |     3   |   50
       1      |        3       |     2   |   90
       1      |        3       |     3   |   100
       1      |        3       |     4   |   85
```

In this example there are three competitions:

```
(
    user1 vs. user2,
    user1 vs. user3,
    user2 vs. user3 vs. user4
)
```

My problem is that i need to define a view that gives me the winners in each competition.

Expected Result:

```
 id_tournament | id_competition | id_winner
 ------------------------------------------
        1      |        1       |     2   
        1      |        2       |     3  
        1      |        3       |     3
```

This can be solved with the query:

```
SELECT 
    id_tournament,
    id_competition,
    id_user as id_winner
FROM (

    SELECT * FROM competitions ORDER BY result DESC

) x GROUP BY id_tournament, id_competition
```

This query however uses a subquery (not allowed in views), so my first solution was to define a 'helper view'as :

```
CREATE VIEW competitions_helper AS (
    SELECT * FROM competitions ORDER BY result DESC
);

CREATE VIEW competition_winners AS (
    SELECT 
        id_tournament,
        id as id_competition,
        id_user as winner
    FROM competitions_helper GROUP BY id_tournament, id_competition
);
```

However this does not seem to give the correct result.
It's result will then be:

```
id_tournament | id_competition | id_winner
------------------------------------------
       1      |        1       |     1   
       1      |        2       |     1
       1      |        3       |     1
```

What i don't understand is why it works when i use Sub-querys and why it gives a different result with the exact same statement in a view.

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot.

Comment: It should be `1      |        1       |     2`, not `1      |        1       |     1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the [`GROUP BY` behaviour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

> In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

I would solve the problem in this way:

```
CREATE VIEW competitions_helper AS (
    SELECT      id_tournament,
                id_competition,
                MAX(result) as winning_result
        FROM    competitions
    GROUP BY    id_tournament,
                id_competition
);

CREATE VIEW competition_winners AS (
    SELECT      c.id_tournament,
                c.id_competition,
                c.id_user
        FROM    competitions c
    INNER JOIN  competitions_helper ch
            ON  ch.id_tournament = c.id_tournament
            AND ch.id_competition = c.id_competition
            AND ch.winning_result = c.result
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i can confirm that it works and have upvoted the solution. It will become visible when i reach rep 15.